# My 7 month old Husky killed a rabbit today in our yard, will that make her aggressive going forward?

Tags: dogs, aggression, husky

We have a 7 month old Husky.  This morning, she caught a rabbit in our back yard.  She was out going to the bathroom and I was getting her food and water when I heard screaming coming from the back yard.  I grabbed a flashlight and discovered she had a rabbit.  She wouldn't release it, so I chased her around the yard until she dropped it and I could get it from her.  She was very aggressive and growled at me, which I figure it normal.

My question is whether or not this might make her more aggressive towards us, or towards the other little dog in our household.  You always hear stories about once a dog tastes blood, that they have a taste for more, but I don't know if those are old wives tales or if there's some accuracy to them.

Comment: Does she normally growl at you when you try and take food or 'her things' from her?

Comment: She growls if she has a toy or bone and she's under the couch and you try to take it from her.

In this situation, she drug the rabbit under my car and was growling at me when I tried to get to it.  I finally had to use a golf club to move her away so I could get it.

Answer (score 4):

The situation was certainly not desirable, but all things considered not out of the norm.

First of all, in comparison to other breeds, Huskies have a more feral temperament. This quality was highly valued by the Inuit who needed strong and independent dogs for their sleighs.

Then you need to keep the situation in mind: the rabbit triggered her hunting instinct, her adrenaline was running high, she had made prey and then you came around and wanted to steal it from her. All but the most timid dog would have reacted that way.

What you did wrong was chasing her around. That only adds to the excitement of the situation and triggers her instinct to protect her prey. Instead, you should call her to you, take hold of the rabbit and hold onto it until she lets go. Do not pull it or yank it around, but make her understand that she should let go. That way you *claim* the rabbit for yourself instead of *stealing* it. Of course that is disappointing for her and she'll try to prevent you from taking hold of the rabbit, but it's better than pushing the adrenaline up even more.

---

> My question is whether or not this might make her more aggressive towards us, or towards the other little dog in our household.

You don't have to be afraid of that. Wild dogs and wolves regularly kill prey to survive and learn to kill from a young age. The easiest prey would be their own pups or injured family members, but they know exactly who is part of the pack and who is suited to become the next meal. The only situations in which a dog would kill a pack member are severe starvation and illnesses like rabies.

Don't treat her any differently or even separate her from the smaller dog. All of you are one pack. Keep it that way and there shouldn't be any problems.

You might want to avoid playing with toys that make squeaking noises when the dog bites into them. They simulate the death scream of a small prey.